# How add Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare 4?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I'm comparing 2 .po files. They have a lot of differences of this type:

**File 1:**

```
#: G:\theme\mytheme\user_dashboard_add.php:1377
```

**File 2:**

```
#: G:\theme\mytheme\user_dashboard_add.php:1100
```

I need ignore that lines. Lines that begin with *"#: G:"* as **Unimportant Text**.

I already add this regex in the **Session Settings** > **Importance tab** > **Unimportant text**:

```
^#: G
```

But Beyond Compare still shows me that lines as different.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The regex you listed only matches on the first few characters in the line. To make the entire line unimportant if it starts with #: G, use the regex:

```
^#: G.*
```